# Posting JSON object to REST using JQ

Tags: ajax

I am trying to post a JSON object to a REST created in Java using JQ's Ajax, however, I'm getting "unsupported media type" error.

Here is the controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "postrest", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String postRest(@RequestBody Person person) throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return "Congrats on successfully posting, " + person.getName() + "!";
}
```

Here is the pojo:

```
package domain;

public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
var person = {};
person.name = "milan";

$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8084/app/postrest",
type: "post",
data: person,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "text",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

EDIT: Turns out this wouldn't work even if I used the old-fashioned Ajax because the server application didn't have Jackson. I can get the old-fashioned way to work now that I'm using the lib, however, I still can't fix the JQ variant. Here's the old-fashioned Ajax code:

```
var person = {};
person.name = "milan";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("post", "http://localhost:8084/springsecurityalternative/postrest", false); //notice that the URL is different here, this is because I'm running using a different app that has Jackson
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(person));

xhr.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out the problem.

Apparently, the server app needed to have Jackson (hence I'm using a different URL now - it's a different app that has Jackson) and the JQ code should look something like this (I had forgotten to JSON.stringify() the data being sent):

```
var person = {};
person.name = "milan";

$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8084/springsecurityalternative/postrest",
type: "post",
data: JSON.stringify(person),
contentType: "application/json", //data type being sent to the server
//dataType: "json", //data type expected from the server
   //context: document.body //by default set to document
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```